# Cortex-M4 custom HardFault_Handler

Tags: gdb, arm, embedded, cortex-m

I'm in the process of writing a custom `HardFault_Handler` for the Cortex M4 -- but for an unknown reason, I am unable to step though any instructions in the handler.

When I break with gdb, I am stuck at the first instruction of the handler. `n` does not proceed to the next instruction, gdb just starts spinning again until I break. OpenOCD shows that I am hitting halting repeatedly, but it doesn't appear that any of the code in my exception handler is being executed... but every time I break, I am in the exception handler.

```
...
Info : halted: PC: 0x08000240
Info : halted: PC: 0x08000240
Info : halted: PC: 0x08000240
Info : halted: PC: 0x08000240
...
```

I know that if I break at main, I can step through the code (in C) up until the point I generate the exception and catch it in my custom handler. However, stepping through the instructions in the handler just puts be at the beginning of the handler.

Here's my handler:

```
.syntax unified
.thumb
.global HardFault_Handler

  .section  .text.HardFault_Handler,"ax",%progbits
HardFault_Handler:
  .size  HardFault_Handler, .-HardFault_Handler

Infinite_Loop:
  mov r0, #0x1
  mov r1, #0x2
  mov r2, #0x3
  b  Infinite_Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.thumb` needs to be replaced by `.thumb_func`.

This directive ensures that the function pointer is a valid for the thumb mode. Thumb mode instructions have odd addresses, while arm mode instructions have even addresses. The directive will [add 1 to the address](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0471i/Babfjhia.html) of the function pointer (i.e. exception vector pointer).

Without this directive, the address of the pointer will be in arm mode (even address), which itself causes an exception. In other words, my exception was being preempted with an exception.

Add `.thumb_func` to explicitly identify this symbol as a thumb-mode function so the linker can do the right thing.

```
.syntax unified
.thumb_func
.global HardFault_Handler

  .section  .text.HardFault_Handler,"ax",%progbits
HardFault_Handler:
  .size  HardFault_Handler, .-HardFault_Handler

Infinite_Loop:
  mov r0, #0x1
  mov r1, #0x2
  mov r2, #0x3
  b  Infinite_Loop
```

Comment: You can I believe also specify the cpu:  `.cpu cortex-m4` instead of the `.thumb_func` (also `-mcpu` command-line option if you you want to use the same assembler over several targets).  Note that on Cortex-M it is possible to implement exception and interrupt handlers directly in C code with no intermediate assembler glue.  This is most often simpler.  You only need to implement a C function with the name `HardFault_Handler` for this to work.  Described [here](https://blog.feabhas.com/2013/02/developing-a-generic-hard-fault-handler-for-arm-cortex-m3cortex-m4/) for example.

Comment: @Clifford I do have that in my `CCFLAGS` already, it didn't seem to work. I think `.thumb_func` is required when using specifically a *function pointer* in assembly. And yes, I would probably normally do it in C, but this is for a class homework :)

Comment: Are you sure CCFLAGS applies to .s files?

Comment: In the Makefile, `$(CCFLAGS)` is just a macro which contains `-mcpu`. I pass this to the assembler (well, actually, gcc) directly, so the macro is expanded. According to `arm-none-eabi-as` `-mcpu` is supported. So yeah, it should do the right thing.

Comment: I appreciate that, but the name CCFLAGS implies flags for the C compiler.  If you are invoking the assembler via the gcc driver then I I am not certain that you don't need to pass the assembelt options via `-Wa` - perhaps not for the the common subset of options?  The thing is that Thumb2 is implicit from the CPU specification because Cortex-M does not support the any other instruction set mode.

Comment: @Clifford Ah ha, I will experiment with this and report back. I didn't realize there was a special switch to pass commands to the assembler. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Assembler-Options.html#Assembler-Options

Comment: Personally I'd run gas explicitly (with ASMFLAGS and a .s rule) rather relying on understanding what gcc does.

Comment: @Clifford the only benefit I'm aware of is access to the preprocessor for defines. As I'm not currently using this feature, that's probably a very good suggestion.

Comment: Good point re preprocessor (although you can also run the pre-processor independently (GNU cpp).

Comment: @Clifford I tried your suggestion. Despite switching to gnu `as` and including `-mcpu=cortex-m4`, `.thumb_func` is still required within the `.s` file.